# What is causing the LNK2005?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, linker-errors, preprocessor-directive

The following program runs just fine if I leave the implementation in the header file d_date.h however, I need it to be implemented through the source d_date.cpp. All of the overloads work just fine but for some reason there is a linker error. It probably has something to do with my preprocessor directives but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Primary Source

```
// File: Driver.cpp
// Note: Used to test our date class with overloaded functions

#include <iostream>
#include "d_date.h"

using namespace std;

bool operator ==(date, date);
bool operator !=(date, date);

void main (void)
{
date date1;
date date2;

cout << "Enter date1 and date2:" << endl;


while (cin >> date1 >> date2)
{
    cout << "Printing date1 and date2" << endl;
    cout << date1 << endl << date2 << endl;

    if (date1 == date2) 
        cout << date1 << " is equal to " << date2 << endl;

    if (date1 != date2) 
        cout << date1 << " is not equal to " << date2 << endl;

    if (date1 < date2) 
        cout << date1 << " is less than " << date2 << endl;

    if (date1 > date2) 
        cout << date1 << " is greater than " << date2 << endl;

    ++date1;
    ++date2;


    cout << "Increment of date1: " << date1 << endl;
    cout << "Increment of date2: " << date2 << endl;

    cout << endl << "---End of Run---" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Enter date1 and date2:" << endl; 
}
}

bool operator ==(date lhs, date rhs)
{
return (lhs.getYear() == rhs.getYear() &&
    lhs.getMonth() == rhs.getMonth() &&
    lhs.getDay() == rhs.getDay());
}

bool operator !=(date lhs, date rhs)
{
   return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

class header

```
//d_date.h
#ifndef DATE_CLASS
#define DATE_CLASS

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

#include "d_except.h"

using namespace std;

class date
{
public:
  date (int mm=1, int dd=1, int yyyy=1900);
        // supply date in format MM/DD/YYYY
        // preconditions: 1 <= mm <= 12,
        //                1 <= dd <= daysInMonth()

  void writeShortDate () const;
        // output the date in the format "MM/DD/YYYY"
  void writeLongDate () const;
        // output the date in the format "month day, year"

  void incrementDate(int ndays);
        // add ndays days to the date
        // precondition: 0 <= ndays <= 365

  int numberOfDays() const;
        // return the number of days into the year

  int getMonth() const;
        // return the month as integer value 1 to 12
  int getDay() const;
        // return day of the month
  int getYear() const;
        // return the year

  void setMonth(int mm);
        // update the month
        // precondition: 1 <= mm <= 12
  void setDay(int dd);
        // update the day
        // precondition: 1 <= dd <= daysInMonth()
  void setYear(int yyyy);
        // update the year
        // precondition:  if the date is February 29,
        //                yyyy must be a leap year
  int daysInMonth() const;
        // return number of days in the month

  bool isLeapYear() const;
        // is the current year a leap year (true/false)

  bool operator >(date);
  bool operator <(date);

  date operator ++();
  date operator ++(int);

  friend istream& operator >> (istream& , date& );
  friend ostream& operator << (ostream& , date );


private:
  enum monthName {Jan = 1, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun,
                  Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec};
        // private type used by date

  int month, day, year;
        // private members that specify the date

};
```

I didn't include the rest of the header because it's a bunch of functions within it and it a little long.

This is the implementation for the overload functions

```
//implementation of member overload operators
//d_date.cpp
#include "d_date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

istream& operator >> (istream& istr, date& rhs)
{
char temp;
int m, d, y;

istr >> m >> temp >> d >> temp >> y;

rhs.setMonth(m);
rhs.setDay(d);
rhs.setYear(y);

return istr;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& ostr, date rhs)
{
ostr << rhs.month << "/" << rhs.day << "/" << rhs.year;
return ostr;
}

date date::operator ++()
{
this->incrementDate(1);
return *this;
}

date date ::operator++(int)
{
date temp = *this;

this->incrementDate(1);

return temp;
}

bool date::operator >(date rhs)
{
if (this->year > rhs.year)
    return true;
else if (this->year == rhs.year)
    return this->numberOfDays() > rhs.numberOfDays();
else
    return false;
}

bool date::operator <(date rhs)
{
if (this->year < rhs.year)
    return true;
else if (this->year == rhs.year)
    return this->numberOfDays() < rhs.numberOfDays();
else
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You do compile *both* files? And the *link* both the generated object files together?

Comment: Yes everything is compiled together. The error is LNK2005 http://i.imgur.com/7IAd7l1.jpg

It all works when the functions are simply put into the .cpp exclusively and not used in the header however I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do that. The header came pre-constructed my job was to modify it and add overloaded operators

Comment: Are you using the `#include` directive to include source files? Do you have non-inline function definitions in header files?

Comment: Yes, I am if you look above I posted 3 files excluding the fourth exception file which is not to be modified by me and is only used by the d_date.h which is the header that I do show. There are no inline as far as i can see

Comment: are you running in Visual studio?

Comment: yes I'm in visual studio express 2013, I uploaded the entire source file here http://www.mediafire.com/download/wibbcapoqm4bqvv/Lab+02.zip like I said I can make it work by moving all the functions to either the header or the implementation cpp but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do that and would like to have them separated if possible and can't seem to make it work

Comment: Find in all files string .cpp" (with period at start and double quote mark at the end). If there is a line `#include "<something>.cpp"` then that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is "a bunch of functions within it" in the header file.

If you put a function definition in a header file, it will be defined in all [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit) (i.e. source files) where the header has been included.

There are basically three ways to solve this:

1. Use the linkage-specifier keyword `inline` to make the function inline, like e.g.

   ```
   inline int date::daysInMonth() const {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Make the function definitions inline in the class specification, like e.g.

   ```
   class date {
       ...
       int daysInMonth() const {
           ...
       }
       ...
   };
   ```
3. Move the definitions from the header file, and put them in a source file.

Comment: I think the easiest is probably just to move all the definitions to the source, because I've already tested it and it works. Hopefully that is allowed by my teacher haha!